# How do I create a fading effect in my videos?

Tags: after-effects, motion, motion-graphics

I am trying to make a seamless tunnel ; so I want to fade it in distance. I have tried using set matte but doesn’t seem to work.Any help…..

I have attatched the project file here https://bit.ly/3obiTPA

Comment: A little bit more info about how you're using set matte and what is going wrong would help people answer your question.

Comment: Also, you ask for "Any help" which seems to confuse people. Do you accept answers that use other tools than After Effects or not?

Answer (score -1):

While it really does depend on what software you use, I'll provide the steps on how you do it with ClipChamp Create (the software I use)

*In the video editor:*

1. Click on the element you wish to create a fading effect
2. Select the ***Fade*** option at the top of the screen
3. Adjust the sliders to your liking!

Hope this helps!